angular-calendar : order event by meta data?
I have implemented angular-calendar from (https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar) in my angular project and it works fine.
Somehow, users ask me to make it better.
Now I'm trying to show events by users in the Week View.
Each user have a specific color.

I would be better if each color/user appears on the same column each time. For example, pink on the left, red in the middle, and green on the right.
Is there a way to do this ?
